# PrimeFaces @PushEndpoint with @PathParam is NOT working sometime

Tags: java, primefaces, atmosphere, primefaces-push

I'm using PrimeFaces 6.0 and Atmosphere Run Time 2.4.3. I'm following Chat example and are facing with 'unknown' issue which Push message works sometime and do not work sometime. I have been trying to debug to understand what the issue is but no luck so far.

I have posted here configuration and code, almost the same as we have many examples around.

```
1. pom.xml

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

2. web.xml

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

3. Resource class

@PushEndpoint(value="/{room}/{user}")
@Singleton
public class RoomResource {

@PathParam("room")
    private String room;

    @PathParam("user")
    private String user;



@OnOpen
    public void onOpen() {
        logger.info("onOpen {} for room {} and user {}", new String[]{endpoint.toString(), this.room, this.user});

            eventBus.publish(room + "/*", "test data");
    }

We push the message as

    eventBus.publish("/room_111" + "/*", "user data");

The output is
Sometime onOpen give output as



onOpen AtmosphereResource{
         uuid=187feb09-c9da-4b5d-afe6-5c19c0b4868b,
         transport=WEBSOCKET,
         isInScope=true,
         isResumed=false,
         isCancelled=false,
         isSuspended=true,
         broadcasters=/{room}/1234,
         isClosedByClient=false,
         isClosedByApplication=false,
         action=Action{timeout=-1, type=SUSPEND}} for room **null** and **user** null
```

But sometime I see room and user do have data correct.

Please advice and help.

And please help me to understand what @PushEndpoint(value="/{room}/{user}") is

If we send "/room_1/123" or "/room_2/345" , it means we push message to the same channel right?

I'm experiencing the channel is working not stable enough. Sometime the message is NOT sent to everyone subscribed to the channel. I'm totally got stuck. Please help.

Update:
There are 3 cases, which onOpen happens

1. Correct one
   11:29:22 INFO [http-bio-8080-exec-7]:pad.controller.TestResource.onOpen()43 - onOpen AtmosphereResource{
    uuid=e6aa499b-6962-446e-a26f-f9ca1f768335,
    transport=WEBSOCKET,
    isInScope=true,
    isResumed=false,
    isCancelled=false,
    isSuspended=true,
    broadcasters=/{room_112}/9999,
    isClosedByClient=false,
    isClosedByApplication=false,
    action=Action{timeout=-1, type=SUSPEND}} for room {room_112} and user 9999
2. Wrong Case 1
   11:27:54 INFO [http-bio-8080-exec-8]:pad.controller.TestResource.onOpen()43 - onOpen AtmosphereResource{
    uuid=b43d6cea-cdcd-498f-b83b-7377130f5a34,
    transport=WEBSOCKET,
    isInScope=true,
    isResumed=false,
    isCancelled=false,
    isSuspended=true,
    broadcasters=/{room_112};jsessionid=9082465FABC76CC67477F2BC8C513D7A/9999,
    isClosedByClient=false,
    isClosedByApplication=false,
    action=Action{timeout=-1, type=SUSPEND}} **for room {room_112};jsessionid=9082465FABC76CC67477F2BC8C513D7A and user 9999**
3. Wrong Case 2
   11:29:06 INFO [http-bio-8080-exec-2]:pad.controller.TestResource.onOpen()43 - onOpen AtmosphereResource{
    uuid=a34f7912-47ac-4f22-a7d5-f56a545bcea5,
    transport=WEBSOCKET,
    isInScope=true,
    isResumed=false,
    isCancelled=false,
    isSuspended=true,
    broadcasters=/{room_112}/9999,
    isClosedByClient=false,
    isClosedByApplication=false,
    action=Action{timeout=-1, type=SUSPEND}} **for room null and user null**

Thanks,

Comment: Could anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Any one has experience on it? Please contact me and help